# Best practice for handling invalid function arguments?

Tags: c++

What is the best way to handle invalid function arguments? (I understand there is no sinuglar best way, because it depends on the situation, but read "best" here as "a common practice").

Let's say I have the function

```
template<typename T> std::pair<T,T> min_max(const T* v, const size_t n){
    if(n <= 0){
        throw std::invalid_argument("Array of size zero passed as argument.");
    }
    T min = v[0], max = v[0];
    for(size_t i = 0;i < n;++i){
        if(v[i] < min){
            min = v[i];
        }
        if(v[i] > max){
            max = v[i];
        }
    }
    return std::make_pair<T,T>(min, max);
}
```

which returns a pair containing the smallest and the largest value in the array v. But if the size n is less than or equal to zero, there are no values to extract, so I can't really return anything. Should I throw an exception (like done in this example)?

Thank you.

Comment: Your function, your semantics. Just remember to document them well. You may be interested in some options I discussed in an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1026073/96780) to this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1026042/96780).

Comment: `size_t` is an *unsigned* type. It cannot be less than zero, so you might as well compare `t` for equality to zero.

Comment: IMO, if the preconditions are documented and the caller can reasonably ensure they are met, throwing is the right thing to do. If this is not desired, you can rename the function to something like `try_min_max` and return something like `boost::optional<std::pair<T,T>>`. However, then you are burdening the well-behaved callers with extra work to accommodate the badly-behaved ones.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I think what dlf said about specifying it in the documentation makes sense. If the documentation isn't followed I think it's reasonable to throw an exception.

Comment: Raymond Chen has [something interesting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/12/10/9934911.aspx) to say about this topic.

Comment: There are two major schools of thought on this.  In Defensive Programming, you would definitely validate all of your inputs.  In Design by Contract, you explicitly specify what the valid inputs to your method are and leave it up to the caller to ensure that your method was called with valid parameters.

Comment: Another approach to consider is to define semantics that can regard edge cases as valid.  Although negative size should be an error, zero size may be handled by allowing the caller to specify "initial" minimum and maximum values.  This will also help in cases where a caller may want to treat any minimum value which isn't less than -12,500 as -12,500 and any maximum value that isn't greater than 12,500 as 12,500.