# While iterating through a string, why am I NOT getting out of range error, even though I'm already beyond its length?

Tags: c++, indexoutofrangeexception

My code is literally this:

```
int main(){
    string s = "Success!\n";
    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) cout<<s[i];
    return 0;
}
```

string s is of length 8; and even though I've used an iterator 'i' that goes beyond the string's length, I do not get any error. Why?
Output is:

```
Success!
```

WITH A NEWLINE, I have not even put a newline character

Comment: because `operator[]` doesn't check string size, use `s.at(i)` and exception will be thrown

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When implementing operator\[\] how should I include bounds checking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026042/when-implementing-operator-how-should-i-include-bounds-checking)

Comment: But you did put a newline character.  That's what `\n` is.

Comment: Do not add "SOLVED" to your question title. Everyone can see you've accepted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> string s is of length 8

no it's not, it's 9.

> and even though I've used an iterator 'i' that goes beyond the string's length, I do not get any error

You're not going beyond the string's length, you go *equal* to the string's length. This is defined as returning a null character. Even if you went beyond the string's length with `operator[]`, this is *undefined behavior*, not expected to throw an exception.

> I have not even put a newline character

... yes you did.

Comment: Thanks! 
Sorry, my bad!  
But, it does not produce error even when
I use i<=15
why?

Answer (score 1):

As per the definition of [subscripting (bracket) operator for string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%5B%5D/):

> char& operator[] (size_t pos);
>
> If pos is equal to the string length, the function returns a reference to the null character that follows the last character in the string (which should not be modified).

`"Success!\n"` is a string of length 9. With `S` at index 0, `!` at index 7, and `\n` at index 8.  So when you reference s[9], it's returning back the null `\0` char.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `cout << s[i]` use `cout << s.at(i)` and you will get the results you want.